# Convert date to full length

Tags: php, date

I think this is asked before but i didn´t find it so here is the question:

How do i convert this:

```
2014-03-06 01:02:22
```

to this:

```
March 06, 2014 at 1:02 am
```

Need this in php.

Thanks!

Comment: look at the date function and the strtotime function

Comment: What did you try, mister lazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy if you have a valid date.

The procedural version of this is:

```
$date = '2014-03-06 01:02:22';
$unixTimestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date('jS m y', $unixTimestamp);
```

You can use any format you want instead of `jS m y`, check the full list here: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php